# Add a navigation button for a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, bindingsource

I´m writing a code for a simple CRM system containing a Form with a DataGridView and some text fields. The code is written in VB.net.

The DataGridView is linked to a BindingSource, the text fields are connected to the DataGridView and populated by selecting a DataGridViewRow and that works fine.

Code:

```
Form1.CRM01Form2MainID.Text = Form1.DataGridView1.Rows(Form1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(1).Value
```

I'd like to add navigation buttons (to navigate rows up and down) and for specific reasons I don't want to use a BindingNavigator.

I use the following code to select the next row:

```vb
rowidScroll = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index (dim is public)
DataGridView1.Rows(rowidScroll + 1).Selected = True
```

The issue is that the selected row will indeed move one position down but the `DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index` isn't updated by 1. As a result the navigation stops after one step and the text fields aren't updated.

It would be appreciated if someone can explain how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using the grid at all in code. You should be doing exactly what the `BindingNavigator` does, i.e. use the `BindingSource`. The `BindingNavigator` is simply a UI for the `BindingSource`, specifically the `MoveFirst`, `MovePrevious`, `Position`, `Count`, `MoveNext` and `MoveLast` members. If you want to create your own UI then you do it for the same members or, at least, the ones you want to expose. For instance, if all you want is to move forward and back by record then all you need is to call the `MovePrevious` and `MoveNext` methods:

```
Private Sub movePreviousButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles movePreviousButton.Click
    myBindingSource.MovePrevious()
End Sub

Private Sub moveNextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles moveNextButton.Click
    myBindingSource.MoveNext()
End Sub
```

I'm not 100% sure but I think that those methods will simply do nothing if there is no previous or next record to move to, but you should test that. Either way, it's probably a good idea to disable a `Button` if it can't do anything useful:

```
Private Sub movePreviousButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles movePreviousButton.Click
    myBindingSource.MovePrevious()
    SetNavigationButtonStates()
End Sub

Private Sub moveNextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles moveNextButton.Click
    myBindingSource.MoveNext()
    SetNavigationButtonStates()
End Sub

Private Sub SetNavigationButtonStates()
    movePreviousButton.Enabled = (myBindingSource.Position > 0)
    moveNextButton.Enabled = (myBindingSource.Position < myBindingSource.Count - 1)
End Sub
```

You should also not be manually moving data between the grid and other controls.  You should be binding to those controls too, e.g.

```
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myBindingSource, "SomeColumn")
```

Your `TextBox` will then automatically display the `SomeColumn` value from the current row.  Any editing done via the `TextBox` will also be automatically pushed to the data source.